# handler class calling another handler via Server.Execute() - Error executing child request

Tags: c#, httphandler

I have a bit of code inside a c# class library which runs in the context of a handler. This bit of code makes a call to another handler (*inside the context of the same IIS website*) via Server.Execute() thusly:

```
var htmlWriter = new StringWriter();
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("/myroot/folder1/myhandler.ashx", htmlWriter);
```

The 2nd line throws an unhandled exception:

> Error executing child request for...[vir-path]

Just for context, the following works fine:

```
HttpContext.Current.Server.Execute("/myroot/folder1/mypage.aspx", htmlWriter);
```

I have googled all over and found several references saying to do this in my web.config:

```
<httpHandlers>
   <add verb="*" path="*.ashx" type="System.Web.UI.SimpleHandlerFactory" />
</httpHandlers>
```

I have tried several variations and permutations of the above Web.config setting, but always the error is the same. I can set a breakpoint in my handler at the 2nd class-level variable declaration, and the breakpoint is hit. But stepping to the next line (another variable declaration) throws the exception.

```
private HttpContext _context;
private string _physicalPath = string.Empty; // blows up here
private MasterPropertySet _propSet; // never gets here
```

I have to use Server.Execute() because I get 404-unauthorized errors using WebClient() or similar. Is there any way to make this work?

Comment: did you find a way to get it to work?